# How to identify realip from two proxies? (nginx)

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have website server, which have two proxy ( squid, CF ), they use different header for getting real ip.

I guess nginx command

> set_real_ip_from ;
> real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

can use only once in a server block. How can i set two? Is there any way to properly get real ip from both two?

> set_real_ip_from ip_from_proxy_one
> real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;  // if from proxy one, then get ip from X-Forwarded-For
>
> set_real_ip_from ip_from_proxy_two
> real_ip_header X-CF-connecting-ip; // if from proxy two, then get ip from X-CF-connecting-ip

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about going one level up and do it checking the http header in your application? I can't see a reason to "really" need it...

Comment: ...or go a level down, and make your proxy (CF) use X-Forwarded-For https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-Does-CloudFlare-have-an-IP-module-for-Nginx-

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone searching for the solution, I have come up with [this approach](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/how-to-use-multiple-real-ip-headers-with-nginx).

You can see it's possible to set maps depending on external service IP addresses to define variable defining which HTTP header to use, and then set `real_ip_header` using that variable. But the following **won't work** because variables are not parsed for `real_ip_header`:

```
# DDoS protection service
geo $use_x_real_ip {
  default 0;
  186.2.160.0/24 1;
}

# Cloudflare
geo $use_x_cf_connecting_ip {
  default 0;
  103.21.244.0/22 1;
  103.22.200.0/22 1;
  103.31.4.0/22 1;
  # all other Cloudflare's ranges ...
}

map "$use_x_real_ip:$use_x_cf_connecting_ip" $real_ip_header {
  default 'X-Forwarded-For';
  "1:0" 'X-Real-Ip';
  "0:1" 'CF-Connecting-IP';
}

# here, the real IP header will be set to either X-Real-Ip or CF-Connecting-IP
real_ip_header $real_ip_header;
```

Comment: See Danila's discussion that goes beyond determining that this attempted solution won't work to present a working alternative: https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/how-to-use-multiple-real-ip-headers-with-nginx.